# Spark Dataset — Avoid duplicating Scala case class fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark, case-class

It is often the case that I want to type two Spark Dataset with very close columns like so:

```
case class Car (
  serial_number: Int,
  year: Int,
  brand: String,
  colour: String,
  horsepower: Int,
  weight: Int,
  width: Float,
  length: Float,
  seats: Int,
  owner: String,
  mileage: Int
)

case class CarWithOptionalMileage (
  serial_number: Int,
  year: Int,
  brand: String,
  colour: String,
  horsepower: Int,
  weight: Int,
  width: Float,
  length: Float,
  seats: Int,
  owner: String,
  mileage: Option[Int]        // <--- this is the only different field
)
```

I'm aware that a `case class` cannot extend another `case class`, however could there be a way to avoid all this field duplication and just specify the differing fields in the `CarWithOptionalMileage`?

Comment: Why not association instead. Like I create a common class case class CarCommon(.// All common fields..) now add that in the case CarWithOptionalMileage (common: CarCommon, ..// extra). This will created nested case classes. Do you want to avoid the nesting ?

Comment: @AvishekBhattacharya Up until now, I think nesting is still the way to go. However, since you mentioned it, is there any way to avoid the nesting?